# Is my method to update textview from a volley response the 'Android way' the right way?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have a fragment that sets the textViews from a data object. This data object is initially null when the fragment is created but gets updated after a network request. Now to update the textviews I create a function 'updateAll' and pass the fragment to the callback function that handles the network response. And once the data is set to the data object I call 'updateAll' from the fragment reference.

Example :

```
class someFragment extends Fragment {
    private Textview foo;
    private dataObject obj;

    ...
    public onCreate(...) {
       this.obj = new dataObject();
       sendRequestToVolley(..., new VolleyCallbacks(this));
    }
    public onCreateView(...) {
       ...
       foo.setText(obj.someVar);
    }

    public void updateAll() {
        foo.setText(obj.someVar);
    }
}


class VolleyCallbacks implements someInterface {

    public VolleyCallbacks(someFragmment fragment, dataObject obj) {

     this.obj = obj;
     this.fragment = fragment;
    }

     public onSuccess(Response r) {
        obj.updateData(r);
        this.fragment.updateAll();
     }
}
```

Is this the correct way to do this? Is there a better method?

Comment: Instead of a `dataObject` as a private member of the fragment, you could pass it as a parameter to `updateAll()`. I would probably just name the method `update()` as it appears to only update the UI with a single value.

Comment: instead of fragment which you pass in VolleyCallbacks you can pass reference of interface and used interface for it. there might be memory lick.

Comment: You can also look at the Data Binding library. It is a good alternative to doing all of this by hand.

Comment: change your update function to `updateAll(DataObject dataobject)` is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code looks mainly good. I see one issue: you're keeping the Fragment as a strong reference. It can generate a memory leak if the fragment is destroyed (ie. the user presses back) before the network call is completed. To prevent that, you should use a WeakReference.

I also wouldn't modify your data object inside the callback class. It's better to let the fragment modify it since he is the one holding the reference to it.

I would transform your code like that:

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private Textview foo;
    private dataObject obj;

    ...
    public onCreate(...) {
        this.obj = new dataObject();
        sendRequestToVolley(..., new VolleyCallbacks(this));
    }
    public onCreateView(...) {
        ...
        refreshTextView();
    }

    private void refreshTextView() {
        foo.setText(obj.someVar);
    }

    void onRequestSuccess(Response r) {
        obj.updateData(r);
        refreshTextView();
    }
}


class VolleyCallbacks implements SomeInterface {

    private WeakReference<SomeFragment> fragmentWeak;

    public VolleyCallbacks(SomeFragment fragment) {
        this.fragmentWeak = new WeakReference<>(fragment);
    }

    public onSuccess(Response r) {
        SomeFragment fragment = this.fragmentWeak.get();

        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.onRequestSuccess(r);
        }
    }
}
```